golang+cobra - How to validate individual positional arguments?
I have a fairly straightforward use case …
$ myapp config set key some-arbitrary-value

Making subcommands for config and set is no problem. But I would like key to be constrained to a list of valid config fields, and I would like some-arbitrary-value to be completely unconstrained.
Command.ValidArgs apparently applies to all arguments collectively. So in my case, if I set ValidArgs to my list of valid keys, it’ll fail on my arbitrary value.
The best I could come up with is the following approach:

Create a function that takes an arg position (int) and list of valid values ([]string), and returns a custom PositionalArgs function that validates a single command-line arg against the list. I can use this for the key arg.
Create a similar function that acts like ArbitraryArgs but only for a single arg. I can use this for the value arg. I think I can skip this step but it’d clearly express my intent, which might be helpful for code readers as well as help/usage text generation.
Call cobra.MatchAll() with one each of the above PositionalArgs, and assign the result to my command’s Args. This will compose the two positional validations into what I want.

This seems like a fair bit of fussy work for my simple use case. Plus since PositionalArgs functions require a Command object, I’m not sure how I’d easily test my code. I’m happy to consider alternatives to my proposed approach. Otherwise, I’ll forge ahead. Thanks!

Pulumi has very similar case.
You can check their source code: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/blob/v3.121.0/pkg/cmd/pulumi/config.go#L566

I'd never heard of pulumi. It sounds pretty interesting and is well-starred. Thanks!
